# Evaluation of Method to Classify Large Number of Unlabeled Data

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a small set of labeled training data around 300 examples with 50 features each. Also I have a large dataset of unlabeled data around 30000 examples with 50 features each. What is the best way to find the labels of the second dataset?

The way I currently use is

1. Train a linear classifier as much as possible with the labeled data
2. Use KNN to the unlabeled data 50 at a time and those that are closest to the training examples get to the labeled set.
3. Train the linear classifier again with the new training data

etc...

Comment: What are the labels like? Binary, multiclass, continuous...?

Comment: @AlexL The labels for the classes are numeric for example 1 for the first class 5 for the fifth etc...

Comment: What kind of linear classifier are you using and how well is it performing?

Comment: @AlexL I use SVMs. It has around 70% accuracy. The thing is that this is a methodology that I have thought myself. I was asking to find out if the way I use can be trusted and also what is the best way to tackle this situation meaning what is the best method.

Answer (score 3):

There is a developing subdomain in machine learning called [Active Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_learning_(machine_learning)) where you know the labels for few and use it to suggest other unlabeled examples that would be most useful to have labels for. Then you can label those examples by-hand and re-train the classifier. It's a special form of [semi-supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning).

So how do that? There's a python (assuming you are doing everything in Python) library called [libact](http://libact.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and its source code is on [github](https://github.com/ntucllab/libact). It claims it can work well with `scikit-learn` models.

> In particular, libact models can be easily obtained by interfacing with the models in scikit-learn.

P.S friend of mine says it works well only on Ubuntu. So just make a note of it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: FYI, that's not what active learning is. Active learning is when the algorithm is able to ask the human to label additional examples that it thinks would be most helpful for improving the classifier.

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested it. Basically, he can stick only with semi-supervised algorithms, where human intervention is required. Thanks for the downvote :(

Comment: Edited your answer so I can upvote it

Answer (score 2):

The procedure you are using resembles a technique called self-training. The way it normally works is

1. Train the classifier on your labeled data.
2. Use it to predict the labels on all the unlabeled data.
3. Assume that the classifier is correct for the unlabeled examples for which it is most confident and add them to the labeled training data.
4. Go back to step 1.